# Copper Eating Giant Spiders?

Tags: creature-design, aliens, environment

"...100 Million Years Ago, Following the Glaciation that killed off most fish, a new dominant Phyla emerged. The Spider-Bats, as they are called, were giant spiders with 10 legs that were roughly 12 feet tall. They lacked a brain and only had basic thinking capabilities. They had wings, but were unable to fly, due to their weight. They used to use their wings to scare off predators, but by that time, 100mya, they had killed off most of their predators and no longer needed their wings. New studies show that they did not actually eat their predators. They most likely ate the soil. Our planet's soil has a very high copper content, and they may have used the copper to get their energy to live..."
-Excerpt from *Looking Back, by Krihitori Polsti*

Just wondering, would any part of this **actually** be possible?

Comment: It is weird in about 5 different ways.  Sort of a cross between a fever dream and a bad translation.

Comment: You seem to be asking about a creature in a third party work of fiction, we don't really answer those. If you were asking for yourself, you would have needed to give us a great deal more context to work with. Interestingly, the number of hits for the purported author on google is a whopping 0

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Krihitori Polsti is a fictional character I invented who is writing about an extinct species.

Comment: Ah, just as well I didn't vote to close as off-topic then. Can you fill us in on details about the planetary conditions (atmosphere, gravity), other extant species and anything else which might help answerers?

Comment: Does it have to be science-based?

Comment: *"A new dominant Phyla":* The word *phyla* is plural; the singular is [*phylum*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/phylum).

Comment: I will give an upvote for sentences that are grammatically correct english and have been spellchecked, and for a flow of ideas that is reasonable and not jarring.

Comment: What's copper got to do with it?

Comment: ...you really need to re-write this post. You jump from idea to idea without properly explaining each one, and your grammar is hard to follow.  In any case, this is probably not possible; copper might contain minerals, but animals need to take in energy from the food they eat. latent copper probably doesn't have much energy.

Comment: "They lacked a brain and only had basic thinking capabilities" - while there certainly are lifeforms that lack brains, they don't think at all.  What concept are you trying to communicate here?

Comment: `...were giant spiders with 10 legs that were roughly 12 feet tall.` Either 12-foot-tall giant spiders with 10 legs, or, 10-legged giant spiders, roughly 12 feet tall. Your way is ambiguous as to whether the spiders are 12' or each leg or the total length of all the legs. Also, instead of calling them giant spiders, consider using "looked like giant spiders", as a spider is a specific form of eight-legged arthropod

Answer (score 5):

> would any part of this actually be possible?

## Partially

### Totally Possible

> 100 Million Years Ago, Following the Glaciation that killed off most fish, a new dominant Phyla emerged.

---

> They had wings, but were unable to fly, due to their weight. They used to use their wings to scare off predators, but by that time, 100mya, they had killed off most of their predators and no longer needed their wings

---

> Our planet's soil has a very high copper content

### Somewhat possible

> giant spiders with 10 legs that were roughly 12 feet tall.

This may require some handwaving. Spider growth is constrained by the Square-Cube law. Then again at some point our ancestors were worm-like and we evolved new physiology to get over that. Might be possible for your spiders too.

### Not possible

> They lacked a brain and only had basic thinking capabilities

You can't compute without a computer.

---

> eat their predators.

The sentence does not make sense. If you are doing the killing and the eating then YOU are the predator.

Herbivores killing their predators is not unheard of though.

---

> they may have used the copper to get their energy to live

There is too little energy in copper ores for animals to thrive in. It's just mostly microbes that are able to thrive on [lithotrophy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithotroph).

Comment: `...used the copper to get their energy to live` does not imply they got their energy from copper, just that copper was involved in the process. Academic weasel words exist to conceal uncertainty, in this case, "We don't know for sure, but we think copper was part of their diet."

Comment: Good answer, but I propose 2 changes. 1. If we dive into technicalities you don't require a brain to move. Jellyfish do it. Plants move with the sun. Alternatively a spinal cord or nerve knot can do a lot of 'thinking' while not being classified as a brain. 2. Tigers can hunt humans, while humans can hunt tigers. Predator and pray aren't mutually exclusive.